# What's the difference between $O(1)$ and $o(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

What's the difference between $O(1)$ and $o(1)$ ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364444/5345646).

Comment: I know the definition:-)

Comment: Then what's the question? The two are different sets, one being a (proper) subset of the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function is $O(1)$ if it is bounded from above. It is $o(1)$ if it tends to zero. Any function which is $o(1)$ is also $O(1)$.

For example, $\sin^2 x$ is $O(1)$ but not $o(1)$, and $1/x$ is both $O(1)$ and $o(1)$.